# How to exclude urls from Apache mod_deflate via SetEnvIfNoCase

Tags: magento, apache2, expressionengine, mod-deflate

I'm dealing with a Magento site that has a 3rd party CMS integration.  When I enable Mod_deflate via the .htaccess file most of the site works well.  All of the pages that pull the information from the CMS show "gobbledy-gook" and it apprears that what is supposed to apprear is not getting decompressed.

I'm attempting to simply exclude parts of the site that employ the CMS from compression (including the home page), however, I'm not sure if I can exclude urls from mod_deflate via SetEnvIfNoCase.  A yea, nea or syntax help would be appreciated.

Here are my lines:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(/site/*)" no-gzip dont-vary #exclude www.example.com/site/
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(/)" no-gzip dont-vary #only exclude homepage or index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution. If you need to gzip your site, but for some reason parts of your site don't react well to gzip compression - such as the 3rd party CMS integration with Magento. Enable mod-Deflate in your .htaccess file and include this line:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/yourdir(.*) no-gzip dont-vary
```

yourdir being the directory where your cms is installed.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) you would want

```
SetEnvIf
```

not

```
SetEnvIfNoCase
```

Comment: Gave that a try, but a no. If this is possible I think the problem I'm having is how my REQUEST_URI is structured.  There is clear documentation about structuring the REQUEST_URI for a MIME type, but not an actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

AllInOne, would the correct syntax be?:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/site/*)" no-gzip dont-vary`

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/)" no-gzip dont-vary`